# Excel Pivot table in ASP

Tags: asp.net, excel, .net-3.5, c#-3.0

Is there a way I can create Excel Pivot tables using ASP .NET 3.5 with C# ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at

- [Worksheet.PivotTableWizard
  Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.pivottablewizard(VS.80).aspx)
- [Creating a PivotTable
  Programmatically](http://blogs.msdn.com/andreww/archive/2008/07/25/creating-a-pivottable-programmatically.aspx)

Comment: Thank you @astander, but I am new to creating Excel in C#. Can you please provide me some tutorial / sample code where I can learn how this can be really implemented in my code?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this using a third party product: Gembox professional.

Create an Excel spreadsheet with a Pivot table based on a named range.
Export your data to the spreadsheet, update the name of the range and voila.

(I am not related to Gembox in any other way than being a happy customer)